# Mysql auto deleting event after 3 days

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my MYSQL database called sale as shown below:

[image: sale table schema]

I want to auto delete the sales that are 3 days old and not validated,
I create event but unfortunately it doesn't work here's my code :

```
CREATE EVENT `delete_sale` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR  DO DELETE FROM sale WHERE sale.is_validated = 0 and sale.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Comment: Do you need to delete them? Can't you simply ignore them? It might be useful to know how many sales 'fell through'

Comment: i do appreciate your proposition but i need to delete those sales so that the apartments become available to other customers again

Comment: i would change the criteria for availability.

Comment: it still need the auto update functionality

Comment: Ok. I don't see why

Comment: i resolve the problem by enabling  event_scheduler with the following query SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;  thanks again for your help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem resolved by enabling event_scheduler with the following query SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your event is working, but it's only firing once then deactivating. To fix that, you should add the "ON XOMPLETION PRESERVE" line. Another possibility is that it's not loading properly because it can't quite parse your event code. To really hold MySQL's hand with this, try treating it like a multi statement event, changing the delimiter and adding BEGIN and END. Something like this:

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE EVENT `delete_sale` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR  
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
DELETE FROM sale WHERE sale.is_validated = 0 and sale.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
END &&
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i resolve the problem by enabling event_scheduler with the following query SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; thanks again for your help i really appreciate it